# Doctrine2 does not escape table name on scheme update

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm

I build a doctrine2 entity class `Group` and quoted the table name:

```
/**
 * models\Entity\Group
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="models\Repository\GroupRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="`group`", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="admin", columns={"`admin`"})})
 */
class Group
{
```

But doctrine seems not to quote the table name on each query. When I run `doctrine orm:schema-tool:update --dump-sql` the last two queries are not escaped:

```
ALTER TABLE group DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_6DC044C5814666E9;
ALTER TABLE group ADD CONSTRAINT FK_6DC044C5814666E9 FOREIGN KEY (`admin`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`)
```

Am  doing something wrong here?

**EDIT**

For now I replaced

```
    if ($table instanceof Table) {
        $table = $table->getQuotedName($this);
    }
```

by this

```
    if ($table instanceof Table) {
        $table = $table->getQuotedName($this);
    } /* Start hack */ else if (0 !== strpos($table, '`'))
        $table = "`$table`"; /* End hack */
```

In `\Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform::getCreateForeignKeySQL()` and `getDropForeignKeySQL()`. But of course that is not … ahem … a very good solution.

Comment: I'm in the exact situation. An entity named Group with a table named group. Seems like a huge oversight. I'll recreate and I'll post an issue in their project.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in a similar situation. It seems like the original bug has been fixed, though.

Running:

```
./vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:schema:create --dump-sql
```

Gives this SQL, which is correct.

```
ALTER TABLE groups_user ADD CONSTRAINT FK_F0F44878A76ED395 FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES User (id);
ALTER TABLE groups_user ADD CONSTRAINT FK_F0F44878FE54D947 FOREIGN KEY (group_id) REFERENCES `group` (id);
```

The above table name is properly escaped.

**However**

When attempting to *SELECT* from that table later, I'm getting an error.

```
function getGroupByName($name)
{
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $criteria = array('name' => $name);
    return $em->getRepository('Module\Entity\Group')
        ->findOneBy($criteria);
}
```

Throws:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.name AS name2 FROM group t0 WHERE t0.name = ? LIMIT 1' with params ["The Group Name"]:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group t0 WHERE t0.name = 'The Group Name' LIMIT 1' at line 1
```

As you can see above, in `FROM group t0 WHERE` the table name should be escaped, but is not.

My goofy solution was to keep all the entity names the same and simply update the ORM annotation to use the plural "groups".

In Module\Entity\Group

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="groups")
 */
```

In Module\Entity\User

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Module\Entity\Group", inversedBy="users")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(
 *     name="groups_user",
 *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)},
 *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)}
 * )
 */
private $groups;
```

It's not for the purist, but it means not hacking Doctrine, and the entity name can remain the same.